# Connect to Oracle using dsn(connection string) in pyspark Synapse notebook

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a Connection String : like 'dsn=.....'
uname and password for my oracle db.

I need to connect using the above details but not with hostname like we do for jdbc.

is there any template code for this
I could not get any on the internet?

and what are the packages requried ,i think ojdbc driver jar doesnot work for GenericODBC connections.

Am able to connect using GenericODBC linked service given by Azure where am using an SHIR . But how to achieve this in pyspark code ?

Comment: import pyodbc
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("OracleExample").getOrCreate()
dsn = "your_dsn_name"
uname = "your_username"
pwd = "your_password"
conn_str = "DSN={};UID={};PWD={}".format(dsn, uname, pwd)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:odbc:" + conn_str) \
    .option("dbtable", "your_table_name") \
    .load()